# Pig permission denied while hdfs file is readable

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, hdfs

Running the following commands is sucessful

```
hadoop fs -ls /path/
hadoop fs -cat /path/.pig_schema
```

And all the files in that dir has a `-rwxr-xr-x` permission

However, in the `pig` console, when running:

```
A = LOAD '/path/' USING PigStorage();
B = LIMIT A 5;
DUMP B;
```

Encounters a **permission error**

```
2015-08-27 08:47:59,734 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - You don't have permission to perform the operation. Error from the server: Permission denied
2015-08-27 08:47:59,735 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 2017: Internal error creating job configuration.
```

Any idea why ?

EDIT 1: Added error log

> ---
>
> ================================================================================ Pig Stack Trace
>   --------------- ERROR 2017: Internal error creating job configuration.
>
> org.apache.pig.impl.logicalLayer.FrontendException: ERROR 1066: Unable
>   to open iterator for alias B  at
>   org.apache.pig.PigServer.openIterator(PigServer.java:857)     at
>   org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.processDump(GruntParser.java:746)
>     at
>   org.apache.pig.tools.pigscript.parser.PigScriptParser.parse(PigScriptParser.java:320)
>     at
>   org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:196)
>     at
>   org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:171)
>     at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt.run(Grunt.java:69)  at
>   org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:543)    at
>   org.apache.pig.Main.main(Main.java:157) Caused by:
>   org.apache.pig.PigException: ERROR 1002: Unable to store alias B  at
>   org.apache.pig.PigServer.storeEx(PigServer.java:956)  at
>   org.apache.pig.PigServer.store(PigServer.java:919)    at
>   org.apache.pig.PigServer.openIterator(PigServer.java:832)     ... 7 more
>   Caused by:
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobCreationException:
>   ERROR 2017: Internal error creating job configuration.    at
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler.getJob(JobControlCompiler.java:874)
>     at
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler.compile(JobControlCompiler.java:297)
>     at
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher.launchPig(MapReduceLauncher.java:177)
>     at org.apache.pig.PigServer.launchPlan(PigServer.java:1285)     at
>   org.apache.pig.PigServer.executeCompiledLogicalPlan(PigServer.java:1270)
>     at org.apache.pig.PigServer.storeEx(PigServer.java:952)     ... 9 more
>   Caused by: java.io.IOException: Permission denied     at
>   java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)   at
>   java.io.File.createTempFile(File.java:1879)   at
>   java.io.File.createTempFile(File.java:1923)   at
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler.getJob(JobControlCompiler.java:538)
>     ... 14 more

Comment: What happens if you try a `hadoop fs -ls /` and `hadoop fs -ls /tmp`?

Comment: `/tmp` is `drwxrwxrwt`, and most of its content is `drwx------`

Comment: And do you know the value of your `pig.temp.dir`?

Comment: I run pig with  `pig -stop_on_failure -Dmapreduce.job.acl-view-job=* -Dpig.temp.dir=/tmp`

Comment: make sure you are in mapreduce mode.  pig -x mapreduce or pig

Comment: Can you please try a `hadoop fs -ls /`?

Comment: There are a lot of dirs there, not all of them I can share publicly, do you have any specific directory in mind you think might be relevant to the issue ?

Comment: My question is if you have any permissions issue when listing the root directory, no need to share the contents of the command itself.

Comment: Can you make this work from another location, or by loading data in from an ORC DB for example? -- For people who found this post when looking for [ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34495085/error-1066-unable-to-open-iterator-for-alias-in-pig-generic-solution) here is a [generic solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34495086/983722).